# I have a loop in the Javascript console that is not working. A

Tags: javascript, html, browser, console

I have a loop that I want to use to print all element with a specific class name from a webpage.

```
var arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("wM6scouPXXsFDSZmZPHRo DjcdNGtVXPcxG0yiFXIoZ _23wugcdiaj44hdfugIAlnX”)[i].href
}
```

This code only prints the last element. I have also tried adding a variable and printing it with console.log, it will return an Undefined.

Maybe the URL I am working with is blocking my requests? It only shows the last element and not the one from 1-15.

Comment: The code you posted have syntax error and can not be executed

Comment: 1. You have one curly quote. 2. You do not DO anything with the href

Comment: Perhaps you mean `const arr =     [...document.querySelectorAll("a.wM6scouPXXsFDSZmZPHRo")].map(link => link.href);`

Answer (score 1):

Run this in developer tools of stackoverflow page. getElementsByClassName will get all the elements with same class. It will be an array of elements, loop over each element and access href.

```js
const links = document.getElementsByClassName('question-hyperlink');
console.log(links)
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  console.log(links[i].href)
}
```